# SMTP fallback server not following host list

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

While attempting to use an SMTP host and fallback host (separated by ;) the code failed to connect.  A single host value works if it's the correct value based on environment.

We'd prefer to use the multi-host (fallback) mechanism so we can list multiple hosts instead of evaluating Server's host name in order to execute conditional setting of the SMTP host.

The files `class.phpmailer.php` and `class.smtp.php` in our codebase have version number of 5.2

For reference, I looked up versions of these files on the web:

- https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php
- https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.smtp.php
- [Fallback smtp servers with phpmailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337686/fallback-smtp-servers-with-phpmaileris) a similar question, but winds up using conditional coding.

Is there a configuration setting (php.ini maybe??) that needs adjustment in order for the list of "primary-host;fallback-host" to work as defined?  Thanks, Adam

Comment: Can you show some code and error messages?

Comment: @Pekka웃 For the moment, the host is conditionally-set, so there's no error. I have requested the error message from my Developer who signs on later this evening. At that point I can share more (sorry).

Comment: Version 5.2.what? 5.2.0 is years old, latest is 5.2.14. Multiple servers work just fine in the unit tests - perhaps you should look there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade the version from 5.2.0 to 5.2.14 - once the files were updated we got the expected results.

Thanks to those who commented here (@Pekka and @Synchro).